# Pandas/pyplot scatter plot: set axis labels not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas to generate a scatter plot from some CSV data, like so:

```
data = pd.read_csv(csv_fpath)
ax = data.plot(kind='scatter', x='var_a', y='var_b')
ax.set_xlabel = "Variable A"
ax.set_ylabel = "Variable B"
ax.set_title("My Fancy Scatter Plot")
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
```

My problem is, the axis labels are stubbornly remaining as `var_a` and `var_b`, i.e. the calls to `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel` don't seem to be doing anything.

Am I calling the wrong methods? They seemed to work as expected in an interactive iPython session, but once I put it into a script and saved the figure, this behaviour emerged.

(**Python:** 2.7.6,  **pandas:** 0.15.2, **matplotlib:** 1.4.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I calling the wrong methods?

Erm, you're not *calling* the methods at all.. you're *rebinding* the names of the methods to strings. :-)

Replace

```
ax.set_xlabel = "Variable A"
ax.set_ylabel = "Variable B"
```

with

```
ax.set_xlabel("Variable A")
ax.set_ylabel("Variable B")
```

Comment: Sigh ... and I thought two cups of coffee was enough this morning. ^_^ Thanks!